# How to handle two get request that the second request depend on the first one using setState in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm new to React, and I know that **useState** will not be reflected immediately.

In my first get request I'm getting page informations based on URL instead of pageID because I'm trying to make a custom url when sharing pages instead of looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/pages/:pageId`, so it becomes `http://localhost:3000/pages/DT/:url`. In the second get request, I'm getting templates based on pageID to render templates (houses).

Since I'm not using **pageID**, I cannot use **useParams** to get the value. Instead, I'm trying to set **pageID** like this in the first get request (`setPageId(res.data.page.id)`)

But since I cannot get pageID from the first get request, the second request becomes `http://localhost:8080/api/RE/template/null`.

I've tried `localStorage.setItem("pageId", res.data.page.id)` it works, but I don't want to use local storage set or remove every time. I also tried to make a **setTimeout** for 2 seconds but still it didn't work. In the **useEffect** I've added **pageID** as a dependency but still nothing.. I've also tried using **Promise** and later made like this but **pageID** returns null as well.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCustomUrl()
      .then(() => {
        getTemplates();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

What I want to know is, what is the best approach to handle two request that depends on each other?

```
  const [loadedSharePages, setLoadedSharePages] = useState(null);
  const [loadedTemplates, setLoadedTemplates] = useState([]);
  const [pageId, setPageId] = useState(null);

  const url = useParams().url;

  const getCustomUrl = async () => {
    await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `http://localhost:8080/api/pages/DT/${url}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Respond from the request getCusomUrl-->", res);
        setLoadedSharePages(res.data.page);
        setPageId(res.data.page.id);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    console.log("Shared page --> ", loadedSharePages);
    console.log("pageid: ", pageId);
  };

  const getTemplates = async () => {
    await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `http://localhost:8080/api/RE/template/${pageId}`,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Respond from the request -->", res);
        setLoadedTemplates(res.data.templates);
        console.log("Res.data.templates -->", res.data.templates);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    console.log("Loaded Templates --> ", loadedTemplates);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCustomUrl();
    getTemplates();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one solved my problem.

```
const getCustomUrl = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: `http://localhost:8080/api/pages/DT/${url}`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      });

      setLoadedSharePages(res.data.page);
      setPageId(res.data.page.id);

      return res.data.page.id;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const getTemplates = async () => {
    try {
      const pageId = await getCustomUrl();
      const res = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: `http://localhost:8080/api/RE/template/${pageId}`,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      });

      setLoadedTemplates(res.data.templates);
      console.log("Res.data.templates -->", res.data.templates);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    getTemplates();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do separate Effect for each request that depends on the previous.
This is one simple solution.

You can then think how to do a custom hook for this, etc.

You can set the effect to be depend on some state by adding it to the brackets at the effect parameter.

For example:
(like pseudocode code)

```
useEffect(()=> ...getTheFirstData. then(//update the state1) ,[stateStartAction]);

//will happen when state1 has changed
useEffect(()=> ...getTheSecondData. then(//update the next state) ,[state1]);

//And so on what you need
```

on the code trigger the effect by:

```
setStartAction(!stateStartAction);
```

Comment: I've tried with try catch method and in the second request I've waited `const pageId = await getCustomUrl();` before try catch again. In the useEffect I only put the getTemplates() function and solved it!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to extract actual api requests to something more independent with parameters and without setting the state inside. That way you will be able to move those functions to a separate api.js file (for example) and you will be able to reuse them later, keeping the actual components code clear.

This approach might help you:

```
const getCustomUrl = (url) => {
  return axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `http://localhost:8080/api/pages/DT/${url}`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log("Respond from the request getCusomUrl-->", res);
    return res.data;
  });
};

const getTemplates = (pageId) => {
  return axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `http://localhost:8080/api/RE/template/${pageId}`,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log("Respond from the request -->", res);
    return res.data;
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchMyAPI() {
    const getCustomUrlData = await getCustomUrl(url);
    const getTemplatesData = await getTemplates(getCustomUrlData.page.id);
    
    setLoadedSharePages(getCustomUrlData.page);
    setPageId(getCustomUrlData.page.id);
    setLoadedTemplates(getTemplatesData.templates);
  }
  fetchMyAPI().catch(console.error);
}, []);
```